# Issue with C++ console output

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <iostream>                                                             

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << 1;
   while (true);
   return 0;
}
```

I thought that this program should print 1 and then hung. But it doesn't print anything, it just hungs.
`cout << endl` or `cout.flush()` can solve this problem, but I still want to know why it's not working as expected :)
This problem appeared during [codeforces](http://codeforces.com/) contest and I spent a lot of time on looking at strange behavior of my program. It was incorrect, it also hunged, hidden output was actually debug information.

I tried using `printf` (compiling with gcc) and it behaves as well as `cout`, so this question can be referred to C also.

Comment: You already know that `flush` changes the behavior (`<< endl` implicitly flushes as well). You can read what `flush` does. What else is there to say?

Comment: Cannot repro, this prints 1 with VS2012

Comment: just do `cout << 1 << endl;`

Comment: @Borgleader Try changing build mode (debug/release).

Comment: @ArtemOhanjanyan I did, it prints one in both modes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You writing to a buffer. You need to flush the buffer. As @Guvante mentioned, use `cout.flush()` or `fflush(stdout)` for printf.

**Update:**

Looks like `fflush` actually works with cout. But don't do that - it may not be the fact in all cases.

Comment: Can you explain why it flushes without `while(true);`?

Comment: I mean `printf` and C, not C++.

Comment: All buffers are flushed when process terminates.

Comment: Note that if you would print a character in every `while` cycle you would occasionally see the output as the buffers would be filled from time to time.

Comment: Is it some feature of `main()` function? `Cout` is probably flushed during destruction, but there are no objects in C.

Comment: @ArtemOhanjanyan it's not specific to main. It's just that process terminates after main is exited. That's when all cleanups happen, including buffers flush.

Comment: @ArtemOhanjanyan: Actually, no. `cout` uses the same buffer as `printf`, which can be set with [`setbuf`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_setbuf.htm). When you exit main, you will automatically close all pipes (stdin, stdout, stderr), which will result in the buffer being flushed.

Comment: @Zeta chances are ostream actually does flush on destruction - but this doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @Zeta: So it's connected to `main()`, isn't it? :)

Comment: @ArtemOhanjanyan: C runtimes still support cleanup functions of some kind.  See `atexit` for a standard example; many platforms have additional non-standard mechanisms.  The C runtime will generally set things up using such means so that buffer flushes and so on will happen when the process exits, completely regardless of whether it exits via returning from main, calling `exit`, or some other means.  It isn't too hard to construct particularly uncommon cases where `printf` output is not flushed at all if you know how your platform's underlying C runtime works.

Comment: @claptrap I posted answer first, it's just when I thought about refining the answer I noticed that information is also in another answer. There were several upvotes even before I refined the answer.

Answer (score 2):

That is because `cout` buffers output. You have to flush the buffer for it to actually print.

`endl` and `flush()` both perform this flushing.

Also note that your program hangs because you have an infinite loop (`while(true);`).

The reason it does this is so that if you are printing a lot of data (say 1000 numbers) it can do so drastically more efficiently. Additionally most minor data points end with `endl` anyway, since you want your output to span multiple lines.

Comment: The wording of the question to me suggests that the infinite loop was intentional.

Comment: @GuyGreer: I agree, but since the `;` is easy to miss felt the need to include that bit. Especially given the "I got this code from somewhere" notice.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning `printf`, the same as `cout` holds: you're printing into a buffer, you need to flush it with `fflush(stdout);`. Termination will flush the buffer, this is why you can see the output without your infinite loop.

See [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin) for more information.